# How get old value on select in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel

i have filter form using select dropdown , but i cant get this old value after i submit this filter like input like type text . someone can help ?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Status</label>  
        <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
                    name="user_id" id="user_id" required
                    >
                      @foreach($unit as $id => $nama_unit )
                      <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $nama_unit }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                </select> 
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
```

i add my function controller :

```
public function search_filter_alkes(Request $request)
{   

    $unit        = User::where('roles_id' , 1)->pluck('nama_unit', 'id'); 
    $user_id = $request->user_id;


    $alat = Alat::with('users')->where('user_id',$user_id)
    ->where('jenis', 'Alkes')->
    get();

    session()->put('user_id',$user_id);

    return view('sarpras.alkes',['user_id' => $user_id , 'unit' => $unit,'alat' => $alat  ])

    ->with('user_id', $user_id)
    ;


}
```

Comment: Please share the full blade template code with us and the controller code. If so I will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your code use this and make sure you use **withInput()**

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

<div class="form-group">
     <label>Status</label>  
        <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
                    name="user_id" id="user_id" required
                    >
                      @foreach($unit as $id => $nama_unit )
                      <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('user_id') == $id ? "selected" :""}}>{{ $nama_unit }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                </select> 
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
```

**EDITED**

When you use **redirect()** after post method  you have to use **withInput()** as i mention above example

```
return redirect('route')->withInput();
```

when you use **view()** you have to pass data like as **array** like your code then use same **variable** name

```
    return view('sarpras.alkes',['user_id' => $user_id , 'unit' => $unit,'alat' => $alat  ])

<option value="{{ $id }}" {{ $user_id == $id ? "selected" :""}}>{{ $nama_unit }}</option>
```

Comment: Wait , i will try

Comment: ya and make sure you pass data from controller function also `return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`

Comment: i have error Undefined offset: 0 if i add ->withInput()

Comment: as per your codes i guess `old('user_id') == $id ?` change `$user_id == $id` ?

Comment: Ok wait i will try this

Comment: i use return view . not using redirect route . i add <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ $user_id == $id ? "selected" :""}}>{{ $nama_unit }}</option>  .  $user_id is undefined  . how i can declare first $user_id set null ?

Answer (score 1):

You wil have to compare old value with input key. So replace the below code inside your for loop

```
@if (Input::old('user_id') == $id)
      <option value="{{ $id }}" selected>{{ $nama_unit }}</option>
@else
      <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $nama_unit }}</option>
@endif
```

Comment: I have problem Class 'Input' not found . i use Input on blade , how about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

```
<select name="tags[]" class="form-control select-tag" multiple>
              @foreach($tags as $tag)
   <option value="{{$tag->id}}" {{in_array($tag->id, old("tags") ?: []) ? "selected": ""}}>{{$tag->name}}</option>
              @endforeach
</select>
```

OR

```
<select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender">
        <option value="">Select Gender</option>
        <option value="M" @if (old('gender') == "M") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Male</option>
        <option value="F" @if (old('gender') == "F") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in laravel 8:

```
<select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" required>
   <option value="">Select gender</option>
   <option value="M" @if (old('gender') == "M") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Male</option>
   <option value="F" @if (old('gender') == "F") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Female</option>
   <option value="O" @if (old('gender') == "O") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Other</option>
</select>
```